# 100% CPU usage on obj_msgSend

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, swift2

I upgraded to XCode 7 and Swift 2.
My CPU usage goes to 100% when I try to instantiate and push a specific ViewController.

```
let dummyVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("dummy") as! DummyViewController
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(dummyVC, animated: true)
```

I am able to push any other View Controller, but not this one.
Also, if I don't push the ViewController, my app doesn't freeze(CPU doesn't go to 100%), and this `dummyVC` causes the freeze from everywhere I try to push it.

Here's `Instruments` screenshot.[image: screenshot]

It seems `obj_msgSend` is taking up the maximum CPU usage, but I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811820/my-program-is-spending-most-of-its-time-in-objc-msgsend-does-that-mean-that-obj) that Objective-C is not the real problem. How should I handle this? It is happening only after I updated to Swift 2.

Comment: From the call stack it seems that something weird is happening when the system is trying to setup a UITextView - have a look at that scene and see what is up with the content you are trying to load into that text view

Comment: Surprisingly, there is no `UITextView` in the scene or Controller, only `UILabel`s

Comment: You aren't doing anything on a background queue in this VC?

Comment: Seems that you are creating a recursive condition, what are you doing in the first called methods, such as -awakeFromNib, viewDidLoad etc?

Comment: @Paulw11 I am sorry, there was a `UITextView` in scene although I never used it in ViewController, removing which solved the issue. Thanks for that, but I wanted to know the reason behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out that there was a `UITextView` in Storyboard and this issue happened while setting up the `UITextView` because of the deadlock in constraints.
The height of the `UITextView` was dependent on something which was dependent on height itself, and hence it could never be determined.